# automatic formatting of reference label

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I am using emacs and AUCTeX and would like to change one particular behaviour: When I insert a reference using <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd>, if the target reference is an equation, the reference is automatically included in parentheses. I'd like to get rid of this, that is, I'd just like to get the `\ref{label}`, not `(\ref{label})`.

I tried searching my `.emacs` file and the "customize emacs" option within emacs, but could not find a setting that governs this. I suppose there is one.... If you can just tell me where this is set, I'll be fine doing the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the variable `reftex-label-alist-builtin` in `reftex-vars.el`, you find an entry there saying:

```lisp
(LaTeX "LaTeX default environments"
       ;; ...
       ("equation" ?e "eq:" "~(\\ref{%s})" t
        (regexp "equations?" "eqs?\\." "eqn\\." "Gleichung\\(en\\)?"  "Gl\\."))
```

You see the parenthesis around `\ref`.  You can change this by adding something like this to your `.emacs` after `(require 'reftex)`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist
             '("equation" ?e "eq:" "~\\ref{%s}" t
                (regexp "equations?" "eqs?\\." "eqn\\." "Gleichung\\(en\\)?"  "Gl\\.")))
```